# Determine wheter $a^2-ba = (a-b)a$ and $(a-1)(a+1)=a^2-1$ hold on all rings $(R,+, \cdot)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Determine wheter $a^2-ba = (a-b)a$ and $(a-1)(a+1)=a^2-1$ hold on all rings $(R,+, \cdot)$.

For the first one I have that $a^2-ba=aa-ba = aa + (-ba)$ and I’m supposed to use the distributivity of multiplication w.r.t to addition here?

For the second I have that $(a-1)(a+1)=aa-a+a-1 = a^2-1$ which seems to be true, but am I skipping some steps when doing the multiplication of $(a-1)(a+1) $?

Comment: For the first one you also would need (-ba)=(-b)a [true in any ring] so then can use one of the distributive laws whih says $xy+xz=x(y+z).$ [and then definition of subtraction again].

Comment: Both are true. An important fact is that in any operation an two sided unit always commutes (you don't even need associativity!). This is what you use in showing $(a-1)(a+1)=a^2-1$ but it does not generalize in non commutative ring to $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$. In fact having that equality for all $a,b$ in a ring is equivalent to commutativity

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are fine. It seems like you want it done completely rigorously, so let me spell out the details.

For the first one, let me start from right righthand side of the equation.

$(a-b)a = aa-ba = a^2-ba$

where the only thing I used was distributivity in the first equation. For the second one, we start from the left hand side of the equation.

$(a-1)(a+1)= a(a+1) -1(a+1)= aa + a -1a -1\cdot 1 = a^2+a -a -1 = a^2-1$

The first equal sign, we distribute on the left, and the second equal sign, we distribute on the right. $1a = a$ and $-1\cdot1 =1$ is just using the axiom for the multiplicative unit $1$ of the ring.

Comment: Since the purpose of the exercise is Ring Axioms, I think it is necessary to mention the additive associativity step in the second part.